# Last digit of a number $x^m$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n$ be an integer that is not divisible by any square greater than $1$. Denote by $x_m$ the last digit of the number $x^m$ in the number system with base $n$. Prove that the sequence $x_m$ is periodic with period $t$ independent of $x$.

**Attempt:**

To prove that $x_m$ is periodic with period $t$ independent of $x$, we see that it is sufficient to find the residues modulo every prime factor of $n = a_1 a_2 a_3 \cdots$ where $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ are the prime factors of $n$ listed in ascending order. Then using Fermat's Little Theorem, $x^{a_i}\equiv x \pmod{a_i}$ and thus the periods of each of the modular congruences modulo $a_i$ is $a_i-1$. Thus, the period $t = \text{lcm}(a_1-1,a_2-1,\ldots)$.

I am conjecturing the last result I have, which is that $t = \text{lcm}(a_1-1,a_2-1,\ldots)$, but is there a way to justify it?

**Edit:** Here is the original question.

[image]

Comment: Not independent of x???  That's not true, is it?  Let n = 10.  x = 6, $\{x_m\} = 6$ with period of 1.  x = 5 also has period of 1 and x = 2 has period of 4 and x = 7 has period 4.  If this periods are independent of x then what the heck are they dependent *on*????

Comment: If $\gcd(x,n) = 1$ then the period of {x_m} is $\phi(n)$.  But if $\gcd(x,n) \ne 1$ then the period $\le \phi(n)$ and period $| \phi(n)$.  So I don't see in what sense of the word the period can be said to be "independent" of x.

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand the question.  But if every x_m has a specific period, then all x_m will have a period of any common multiples of the individual periods.  And FLT says all will have period $\phi(n)$.  And $\lcm(a-1,b-1,...) = \phi(n)$.  (If n is square free)

Comment: @fleablood Actually, you can't use that argument. Recall the result you are using is Euler's totient function which only works for $x$ coprime to $n$.

Comment: Hmmmm.... this would be true even if n weren't square free as it doesn't ask you to find the value of t.  Show $0 \le x < n;x_m$ has a period $t_x$. (pigeon hole principal & $nx = a mod n$ having at most one solution assures this) and show $t_{x+n} = t_x$ (trivial).  The t = any common multiple of the  t_x will be a common period for all.  It's not as poswerful and precise as doing it the right way with FLT but it will work (because it can't not work).

Comment: I didn't say $x^{\phi(n)} = 1 mod n$.  I said the period of x^n is $\le$ to $\phi(n)$.  $x^m \ne 1 mond n$ ever if x isn't coprime.

Comment: Don't forget $n$ is square free.  This mean $\gcd(n/\gcd(n,x), gcd(n,x)) = 1$.  So $\gcd(x,n)^{\phi(n)} = 1 mod n/\gcd(n,x)$ and so ..

Comment: @fleablood How do you prove that $x^m \not \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$  if $x$ isn't coprime to $n$?

Comment: If $\gcd(x,n) = d$ then $x^m - k*n$ is never 1 but always a multiple of d.

Comment: @fleablood We are still taking it modulo $n$. So then you have $dk \not \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$?

Comment: $x^m = 1 mod n \iff x^m - kn = 1$ for some $k$.  If $d|n$ and $d|x$ then $d|x^m - kn$ and so $d|1$.  So $\gcd(n,x) = 1$.  So if $\gcd(n,x) \ne 1$ then $x^m \ne 1 mod n$.

Answer (score 2):

Your conjecture is correct, provided that you speak of **a** period throughout, not of **the** period, meaning the shortest period. So you have **a** period $a_i-1$ of each modular congruence modulo $a_i$. Setting $t = \mathrm{lcm}(a_1\!-\!1,\,a_2\!-\!1,\,\ldots)$, the residues of $x^m$ will be the same as the residues of $x^{m+t}$, modulo each prime $a_i$, thus also the residues of $x^m$ and $x^{m+t}$ modulo $n$ will be the same. This means that $t$ is **a** period of the sequence $(x_m)$.

**Added a little later.** $~$When I posted the answer above, I have noticed the first two comments to the question. The confusion in both comments is caused by thinking of **the** period when what we are dealing with is **a** period.

**Added still later.** $~$The answer to the question by "user19405892" in his comment:

> Another part of the question was
>
> "Prove that if $m$ and $n$
>   are relatively prime, then $0_m$, $1_m$, $\ldots$, $(n−1)_m$
>   are different numbers."
>
> This doesn't really make sense to me.

Actually, what "user19405892" really quoted was "If $m$ and $x$ are relatively prime$\ldots$", which does not makes sense to me, either. If this is the actual formulation, then "$x$" is a typo, it should be "$n$", as above: the numbers in the sequence  $0$, $1$, $\ldots$, $n-1$ are the $x$-es. But even in this form the statement is false: for $n=5$ and $m=2$ the sequence $(0_2,1_2,2_2,3_2,4_2)$ is $(0,1,4,4,1)$, which is not a permutation of $(0,1,2,3,4)$. It would be futile to agonize about what the right question should be; it appears that the author of the original question, the one which "user19405892" was supposed to answer, did not think things through. --- Cannot hold this back, though: if $n$ is a prime and $m$ is coprime to $n-1$ (note: $m$ coprime to $n-1$, *not* to $n$), then $0_m$, $1_m$, $\ldots$, $(n−1)_m$
are different numbers. "user19405892": work this out on your own.

Comment: So you are interpreting that the question is to be  *all* {x_m} will have a (possibly not the minimal) period t and *all* {x_m} will have that period?  I have to admit, I did not interpret the question as such but that is the only way the question makes any sense.

Comment: This isn't the minimal period, is it? If not, how would we find the minimal period?

Comment: @user19405892 - By first finding the minimal preriods of the sequences $(x^m \bmod a_i)$; these periods depend on $x$. The group of the nonzero elements of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, for $p$ a prime, is a cyclic group of order $p-1$; let $b$ be a generator of this group (finding some $b$, a basis of discrete logarithms modulo $p$, is not an easy problem). Now, if $x = b^k$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, then the period of $(x^m)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ is $(p-1)/\gcd(k,p\!-\!1)$. The $\mathrm{lcm}$ of the minimal periods of sequences $(x^m\bmod a_i)$ is the minimal period of the sequence $(x^m\bmod n)$.

Comment: @chizhek A second part to this question asks to find all $x$ such that $x_t = 1$ or in other words, $x^t \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. According to the $t$ I found, that happens only when $x$ is coprime to $n$, but it could vary depending upon what $t$ we use.

Comment: @ user19405892 - From what you wrote I do not see what the second part of the question really is. Please write out, verbatim, the whole question as it came to you.

Comment: @user19405892 - Ah: if $x^t\equiv1\pmod n$ for *some* positive integer $t$, then $x$ is coprime modulo $n$. On the other hand, if $x$ is coprime to $n$ and the sequence $x^m\bmod n$ is periodic with **a** period $t$, then $x^{1+t}\equiv x\pmod n$ implies $x^t\equiv 1\pmod n$. Both assertions are true for any positive integer $n$, square-free or not. **Remark.** In your question you should make clear that the sequence $(x^m\bmod n)$ starts with $m=1$, not with $m=0$: if $x$ is not coprime to $n$, then the sequence $x^0\bmod n=1$, $x^1\bmod n$, $x^2\bmod n$, $\ldots$ is not periodic.

Comment: @chizhek Another part of the question was "Prove that if $m$ and $x$ are relatively prime, then $0_m,1_m\ldots,(n-1)_m$ are different numbers." This doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: @user19405892 - I was just advised to move mathematical discussion to the answer. So advised, I am extending my answer.

Comment: Can you add in the answer to the question I just asked too?

Comment: @user19405892 - Where does the original question, the one you are supposed to answer, come from? Is it in a pdf document? If yes, can you place the document on some web server and give me a web link to it? Otherwise, can you paste into your question above a screenshot of the original question? I am curious, I would very much like to see it.

Comment: @chizhek This question was actually from the 1969 International Mathematical Olympiad Longlist, question 19. Here it is: http://tinypic.com/r/wiwv8j/9

Comment: @user19405892 - Tomorrow. Right now I am going home (where I am off the internet). See you.

Comment: Hi, the problem should've said "if $m$ and $t$ are relatively prime..."

Comment: @chizhek Can you try solving the problem if $m$ and $t$ are relatively prime?

Comment: @user19405892 - Sorry, I am becoming rather fed up with question 19 from the longlist of IMO 1969. Half this question either contains typos or is outright false. I hate wasting time guessing how these faults could be repaired. By the way: I downloaded the compendium of all IMO problems (including the longlisted) from 1959 to 2010. Among other things I met again my old pals, the problems of the IMO which I attended. Ah, sweet memories...

Comment: @chizhek Can you tell me how to solve it if $m$ and $t$ are relatively prime?

Comment: @user19405892 - Please, respect my decision that I have had enough of this question. This has nothing to do with you. I am already back from the excursion to stackexchange mathematics and deep into my own work.

Answer (score 1):

Choose an $x$.  Let $\gcd(x,n) = d$.  Let $x = dx'$ and $n = dn'$. $\gcd(x',n) = \gcd(x, n') = \gcd(x',n') =1$.  And as $n$ is square free $\gcd(n',d) = 1$.

By FLT $x^{\phi(n)} = d^{\phi(n)}x'^{\phi(n)} \equiv d^{\phi(n)} \mod n$.

But $d^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \mod n'$ so $d^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 + kn' \mod n$ so $d^{\phi(n)+1} \equiv d + kn'd \mod n \equiv d \mod n$.

So $x^{\phi(n)+1} =d^{\phi(n)+1}x'^{\phi(n) + 1}\equiv dx' \mod n \equiv x \mod n$

**IF** $n$ is square free.

So every $\{x_m\}$ has a period of $\phi(n)$ which is independent of $x$.