# Prove that $0_m,1_m\ldots,(n-1)_m$ are different numbers

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n$ be an integer that is not divisible by any square greater than $1$. Denote by $x_m$ the last digit of the number $x^m$ in the number system with base $n$. Prove that if $m$ and $x$ are relatively prime, then $0_m,1_m\ldots,(n-1)_m$ are different numbers.

I am not sure I understand this question. Does this question make any sense as written, or what is the most logical interpretation of this question because obviously if $m$ and $x$ are relatively prove then $0$ shouldn't be in the list. Essentially we are looking at \begin{align*}0^m &\equiv 0 \pmod{n} \\1^m &\equiv 1 \pmod{n} \\2^m &\equiv b_1 \pmod{n} \\&\vdots\\(n-1)^m &\equiv b_{n-2} \pmod{n}.\end{align*}

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795594/last-digit-of-a-number-xm

Comment: @labbhattacharjee They are similar, but different questions.